# ASPNET Authentication with Multiple servers

Tags: asp.net, oauth, asp.net-identity

I have an ASP.net 4.5.2 app using the token authentication and authorization.  This works as expected.

However, I now want to use two servers.  So the user could get switched from one server to the other.  The issue with this is that when the user is switched, the new server sends a 401 Unauthorized response until the user log in again.

Is there a way to make both servers accept the token?

The main purpose of this is for failover. If server 1 goes down, I can route the traffic to the second one.  I have tested this and it works, except the user is forced to log in again.

Answer (score 1):

The machine key must be the same for all servers serving the app.

[Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/amb/2012/07/31/easiest-way-to-generate-machinekey/) is how to create the machine key in IIS.

Then copy that same key to the other servers.